# Llenar Select JSN Uninform desde una carpeta

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Tengo que llenar un select especifico de un formulario JSN Uniform con los archivos de un directorio, el problema es que al hacer clic en el boton llenar solo me lee un archivo:

¿Como puedo hacer para que me lea y se carguen todos los archivos de mi carpeta en ese select ("45") ?

Codigo:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Llenar Select" onclick="ShowSelected()">';

$directorio = "D:\letritastv\imagenes";
$sizekb = 0.0 ;
$sizemb = 0.0 ;
$dir=opendir($directorio);

while ($file = readdir($dir))
{
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
    {
       $variable_php=$file;
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
         echo 'function ShowSelected(){';
         echo 'var mivar = " '.$variable_php.' "; ';
         echo 'variable = new Option(mivar);';
         echo 'var x = document.getElementById("45");';
         echo 'x.options[1]=variable;';
         echo '}';
         echo '</script>';
   }
}
```

[image: Imagen generada con el codigo]

Answer (score 0):

Primero, este conjunto de instrucciones

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function ShowSelected(){';
echo 'var mivar = " '.$variable_php.' "; ';
echo 'variable = new Option(mivar);';
echo 'var x = document.getElementById("45");';
echo 'x.options[1]=variable;';
echo '}';
echo '</script>';
```

están dentro del while, con lo cual estás definiendo varias veces la función `ShowSelected` (puedes presionar Ctrl+U o buscar la opción de Ver código fuente de la página web, para que veas que está definida varias veces esa función).

Segundo, `x.options[1]` hace referencia al mismo option del select, una y otra vez.

Correcto sería que con el while de php generes un arreglo, y ese lo utilizas dentro de ShowSelected (una sola función, no debes repetirla), para ir creando los diferentes options, claro cambiando el índice (en tu código es siempre 1).

PD: casualmente [aquí](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/) hay un ejemplo relacionado a lo que quieres.